# No e(fx)clipse - IDE option for install

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, efxclipse

I am trying to get JavaFX in eclipse (e(fx)clipse), and I tried to follow these steps here: https://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html. In step 4, however, there is no option for e(fx)clipse - IDE, only e(fx)clipse - Minimal JavaFX OSGi integration bundles. I installed this, but this does not appear to be correct, as it does not give the option for a JavaFX wizard when creating a new project, which is my end goal. I would like to know how to get this wizard to appear and create a JavaFX project using it.

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using? (In Eclipse, go to Help > About Eclipse IDE)

Comment: I am using version 4.11.0, @SansWit

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out I just needed the update site link, which is https://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/3.5.0/site/ for the most recent version (3.5.0)

Comment: Nice. It's now https://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/3.6.0/site/

Comment: The best way to get the most recent version is to go here and scroll down: https://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/

Comment: Just checked, right now we're on 3.7: https://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/3.7.0/site/

Comment: download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/3.9.0/site